# This expression has type a*b*c but type int was expected

Tags: compiler-errors, ocaml, typeerror

I am new to OCaml and I would like to write a function that return the sum of all the multiples of 3 and 5 below z.

Here is what I've done:

```
let rec problemone x y z = match x with
  | x when x > z -> y
  | x when x mod 3 = 0 && x mod 5 = 0 -> problemone(x+1,y+x,z)
  | x when x mod 3 = 0 && x mod 5 <> 0 -> problemone(x+1,y+x,z)
  | x when x mod 3 <> 0 && x mod 5 = 0 -> problemone(x+1,y+x,z)
  ;;
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work and it's telling me that:

```
Error: This expression has type 'a * 'b * 'c
       but an expression was expected of type int
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for function application in OCaml is `problemone (x+1) (y+x) z`, not `problemone(x+1,y+x,z)`.

`(x+1,y+x,z)` is interpreted as a tuple, which is why the error refers to the tuple type `'a * 'b * 'c`. The tuple is passed as the first argument, which is expected to be an `int`. And since functions are curried in OCaml, the compiler will not consider the application of only one argument to a function that expects multiple an error. It therefore only complains about the type mismatch of the first argument.

Comment: Thank's a lot ! It works now. Do you think there is a quicker solution in OCaml to this problem ?

Comment: Your function doesn't actually do what you want yet, so I'd worry about getting it right first. But I think you're on the right track.

Comment: It does now, I just forgot the last line : | _ -> problemone (x+1) (y) (z), and now it works perfectly, for example for z = 999 i get this answer 233168... But I was wondering if there is a quicker/nicer way to solve htis problem

Comment: Nothing that's obvious to me. You can reduce the amount of code quite a bit if you rethink the boolean logic, but that's about all I have to suggest for improvement.

Answer (score 3):

You're passing the single value `(x+1, y+x, z)` (which is a 3-tuple) as the value for the `x` argument (and not passing any values for `y` and `z`).

You'll need to call it as `problemone (x+1) (y+x) z` instead.